# How to make my custom Iterator work with every List?

Tags: java, generics

I have implemented a `SubListIterator` which is a small utility `Iterator` for iterating over sublists of a given list.

Suppose I have a List containing 13500 elements and I want to split it into 7 sublists and use them.

```
 @Test
    public void shouldSplitTheGivenListIntoSmallerLists() {
        List<Long> given = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for (int count = 0; count < 13500; count++) {
            given.add(Long.valueOf(count));
        }

        List<List<Long>> actualSubLists = new ArrayList<List<Long>>();
        for (List<Long> subList : SubListIterator.subList(given, 2000)) { // Line got compilation error
            actualSubLists.add(subList);
        }

        assertEquals(7, actualSubLists.size());
    }
```

Everything works well if I implement the `SubListIterator` directly with `List<Long>`.

Then I wanted to extend my `SubListIterator` to work with every `List` regardless their generic type, so I went changing `List<Long>` to `List<?>` and get the compilation error:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type List<?> to List<Long>`

I tried with `List<T>` and it doesn't work either.

My question is: Is there anyway to achieve my goal which is making the `SubListIterator` to work with every `List`, not just `List<Long>`?

Below is the `SubListIterator`:

```
public class SubListIterator implements Iterator<List<?>>, Iterable<List<?>> {

    public static SubListIterator subList(List<?> given, int itemsEachSubList) {
        return new SubListIterator(given, itemsEachSubList);
    }

    private final List<?> whole;
    private final int elementsEachPart;
    private int fromIndex;
    private int toIndex;

    public SubListIterator(List<?> whole, int itemsEach) {
        this.whole = whole;
        this.elementsEachPart = itemsEach;
        this.fromIndex = 0;
        this.toIndex = elementsEachPart;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return fromIndex < toIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public List<?> next() {
        List<?> nextSubList = whole.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
        fromIndex = toIndex;
        toIndex = Math.min(toIndex + elementsEachPart, whole.size());
        return nextSubList;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This method is not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<?>> iterator() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your support

Comment: It should be an `Iterator<List<T>>`. Post the code you tried with that option. Paste the exact error messages you got from the compiler and tell us which line they refer to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to generalize your SubListIterator.

```
public class SubListIterator<T> implements Iterator<List<T>>, Iterable<List<T>> {

    public static <C> SubListIterator<C> subList(List<C> given, int itemsEachSubList) {
        return new SubListIterator<C>(given, itemsEachSubList);
    }

    private final List<T> whole;
    private final int elementsEachPart;
    private int fromIndex;
    private int toIndex;

    public SubListIterator(List<T> whole, int itemsEach) {
        this.whole = whole;
        this.elementsEachPart = itemsEach;
        this.fromIndex = 0;
        this.toIndex = elementsEachPart;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return fromIndex < toIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> next() {
        List<T> nextSubList = whole.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
        fromIndex = toIndex;
        toIndex = Math.min(toIndex + elementsEachPart, whole.size());
        return nextSubList;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This method is not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: I just discovered that seconds ago. I will accept your answer then.